# mat-select calls compareWith only on mouseover button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a strange behavior with a simple `mat-select`.

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" placeholder="Options"
    formControlName="options" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option.description}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

compareFn(c1: OptionModel, c2: string): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2 : false;
}
```

Code works. If you open the select, check options, reload the page, all works as expected...

BUT

The first time the component has been shown the `mat-select` shows the default placeholder string instead of selected options. If you move the mouse over any component buttons it magically calls `compareWith` function and then values appears.

It seems the `mouseover` event awakens mat-select `compareWith` but I cannot understand why!
Have someone faced the same strange effect?